# A different way to do induction on lists that needs a proof

Tags: list, coq, proof

I have defined an inductive definition of lists (called `listkind`) in order make it easy
for me to prove a specific theorem by induction on `listkind` rather than on list.

```
Inductive listkind {X}: list X -> Prop :=
| l_nil : listkind []
| l_one : forall a:X, listkind [a]
| l_app : forall l, listkind l -> forall a b, listkind ([a]++l++[b]).
```

(With this property, to prove things about lists, I have to prove the cases where a list is [], [a], or [a]++l++[b], rather than the cases where a list is [] or a::l.  In my particular theorem, those cases fit better and makes the proof simpler.)

However, to be able to use listkind in my proof, I have to prove

```
Lemma all_lists_are_listkind: (forall {X} (l:list X), listkind l).
```

Having tried various approaches, I find myself stuck at this point.
I would very much appreciate seeing how to perform such a proof,
preferably with minimal coq magic applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
Require Import List Omega.

Lemma all_lists_are_listkind_size: forall {X}  (n:nat) (l:list X), length l <= n -> listkind l.
Proof.
intros X.
induction n as [ | n hi]; simpl in *; intros l hl.
- destruct l as [ | hd tl]; simpl in *.
  + now constructor.
  + now inversion hl.
- destruct l as [ | hd tl]; simpl in *.
  + now constructor.
  + induction tl using rev_ind.
    * now constructor.
    * constructor.
      apply hi.
      rewrite app_length in hl; simpl in hl.
      omega. (* a bit overkill but it does the arithmetic job *)
Qed.

Lemma all_lists_are_listkind: forall {X} (l:list X), listkind l.
Proof.
intros.
apply all_lists_are_listkind_size with (length l).
apply le_refl.
Qed.
```

The main idea is that your lists have the same size as regular list, and induction on a natural is goes more smoothly than induction on a non trivial shape of list.

Hope it helps,
V.

Comment: if omega is too much "magic" you just have to use the Arith lib to finish the proof.