# Lemma about list and rev(list)

Tags: coq

Trying to prove the following lemma I got stuck. Usully theorems about lists are proven using induction, but I don't know where to move next.

```
Lemma reverse_append : forall (T : Type) (h : T) (t : list T), h::t = rev(t) ++ [h] -> t = rev(t).
Proof.
  intros. induction t.
  - simpl. reflexivity.
  - simpl. simpl in H.

Result:

1 subgoal (ID 522)

T : Type
h, x : T
t : list T
H : h :: x :: t = (rev t ++ [x]) ++ [h]
IHt : h :: t = rev t ++ [h] -> t = rev t
============================
x :: t = rev t ++ [x]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Main answer

Before you start proving your theorem, you should try to *thoroughly* understand what your theorem says. Your theorem is simply wrong.

Counterexample: `2 :: [1;2] = rev [1;2] ++ [2]`, but `[1;2]` is not a palindrome.

Full proof:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Lemma reverse_append_false :
  ~(forall (T : Type) (h : T) (t : list T), h::t = rev(t) ++ [h] -> t = rev(t)).
Proof. intros H. specialize (H nat 2 [1;2] eq_refl). inversion H. Qed.
```

---

#### Minor issues

`rev(t)` should be just `rev t`. Just an aesthetic point, but probably you should get yourself more familiar to writing in functional programming style.

> Usually theorems about lists are proven using induction

This is a pretty naive statement, though technically correct. There are so many ways to do induction on a value, and choosing the induction that works best is a crucial skill. To name a few:

- Induction on the list
- Induction on the *length* of the list

  - arises quite frequently when dealing with `rev` and other functions that preserve length
  - [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18760596/4595904)
- If simple induction doesn't work, consider a custom induction scheme

  - [`nat_ind2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56356131/4595904)

Answer (score 1):

The lemma isn't true as stated. Before proving anything, you should make sure it makes sense. The hypothesis is essentially saying that `h::t = rev (h::t)`. But why would that mean that `t = rev t`? If you remove an element from the start of a palindromic list, it probably *won't* be a palindrome anymore. For example, deified is palindrome ('deified' = rev 'deified'), but eified isn't a palindrome.

For an example in this particular situation, `1::[2; 1] = (rev [2; 1]) ++ [1]`, since both are `[1; 2; 1]`. But `[2; 1]` is not equal to `rev [2; 1] = [1; 2]`.